# Javascript 2d-array unexplainably overwritten (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I have been working on a Sudoku game using React.js. I have a function that will be used to generate a grid and then create a copy of the grid with a specified number of spaces set to '' rather than a number, based on the provided difficulty. However, when running the code, initial grid becomes the same as the altered one. Here is my code:

```
export function generateSudokuTable(difficulty){

    let grid = [[7,2,6,3,5,9,4,1,8],
                [4,5,8,1,6,7,2,3,9],
                [9,1,3,8,2,4,7,6,5],
                [1,6,2,9,7,5,3,8,4],
                [3,9,4,2,8,6,1,5,7],
                [8,7,5,4,1,3,9,2,6],
                [5,3,7,6,4,1,8,9,2],
                [6,8,9,7,3,2,5,4,1],
                [2,4,1,5,9,8,6,7,3]];

    console.log(grid); // Check grid value, result: displays altered output incorrectly

    // Sets number of values to remove for the puzzle table.
    let removedValues = 0;
    if(difficulty === "Beginner"){
        removedValues = 18;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Easy"){
        removedValues = 27;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Normal"){
        removedValues = 36;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Hard"){
        removedValues = 45;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Expert"){
        removedValues = 54;
    }
    else{
        removedValues = 81;
    }

    // Randomly removes the desired number of values
    const puzzle = grid.slice();
    for(let hidden = 0; hidden < removedValues; hidden++){
        let isRemoved = false;
        while(isRemoved === false){
            let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 81);
            if(puzzle[Math.floor(randomIndex/9)][randomIndex%9] !== ""){
                puzzle[Math.floor(randomIndex/9)][randomIndex%9] = "";
                isRemoved = true;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(grid); // Check grid value, result: displays altered output incorrectly
    return [grid, puzzle];
}
```

I have tried altering the way the data is sent to my main app file, the declaration of the variables, and adding in additional copies of the initial input, but nothing has been successful so far. Is there some reason why grid isn't maintaining its initial value inside the function as defined here? Is the problem inside my main app file? Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: `grid.slice()` makes a copy of the *outer* array. The copy will be filled with references to each of the rows in that original array. You'll have to also slice each of them individually to make a complete copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `grid.slice()` only shallow copies the array, so when you update the cells, it will update their rererences. Change that line with a deep copy instead, such as:

```
const puzzle = grid.map(inner => inner.slice())
```

Result:

```js
function generateSudokuTable(difficulty){

    let grid = [[7,2,6,3,5,9,4,1,8],
                [4,5,8,1,6,7,2,3,9],
                [9,1,3,8,2,4,7,6,5],
                [1,6,2,9,7,5,3,8,4],
                [3,9,4,2,8,6,1,5,7],
                [8,7,5,4,1,3,9,2,6],
                [5,3,7,6,4,1,8,9,2],
                [6,8,9,7,3,2,5,4,1],
                [2,4,1,5,9,8,6,7,3]];

    console.log(grid); // Check grid value, result: displays altered output incorrectly

    // Sets number of values to remove for the puzzle table.
    let removedValues = 0;
    if(difficulty === "Beginner"){
        removedValues = 18;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Easy"){
        removedValues = 27;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Normal"){
        removedValues = 36;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Hard"){
        removedValues = 45;
    }
    else if(difficulty === "Expert"){
        removedValues = 54;
    }
    else{
        removedValues = 81;
    }

    // Randomly removes the desired number of values
    const puzzle = grid.map(inner => inner.slice());
    for(let hidden = 0; hidden < removedValues; hidden++){
        let isRemoved = false;
        while(isRemoved === false){
            let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 81);
            if(puzzle[Math.floor(randomIndex/9)][randomIndex%9] !== ""){
                puzzle[Math.floor(randomIndex/9)][randomIndex%9] = "";
                isRemoved = true;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(grid); // Check grid value, result: displays altered output incorrectly
    return [grid, puzzle];
}

console.log(generateSudokuTable("Expert"));
```